# what does ranger redhead mean for Australians?

Tags: meaning, australian-english, catch-phrases

I heard this reference on the Bravo TV show "Watch What Happens : Live" when Andy was speaking to the Housewives of Melbourne. They were giving phrases to the guests that were things Australians say, and the guests were guessing the meanings--only I didn't hear the meaning of "ranger redhead" and was curious. I did however hear one of the guests say ,"oh, I know", "summer high tide", but I'm having trouble connecting the two. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

as a 7th generation red headed Australian, i think i am qualified to answer.....
Australian's love irony and rhyming slang and testing people to make sure that they don't take themselves too seriously (called taking the piss with good humour!!) soooooo.....

Orang-Utan = an auburn haired primate= becomes "rangga" for Red heads.

Bluey--irony for red (but many red heads in Australia have blue eyes) and
 matches nicely with the fact that in Australian slang a "Blue" is a fight and that many Red headed Australians have Irish or Scots ancestry.

Blood nut- a "nut" is slang for head,

Meggs--from "Ginger Meggs" an old Australian strip cartoon series (also inclined to fighting)

Comment: 'matches nicely with the fact that ... a "Blue" is a fight and that many Red headed Australians have Irish or Scots ancestry.' You don't specifically say what makes it match nicely. if it's a *historic cultural assumption* that Scots and Irish are 'inclined to fighting', it might be better to qualify it as a stereotype rather than risk perpetuating it.

Comment: Sometimes people are more inclined to fighting when people are trying to be jovial douchebags towards them!

Answer (score 0):

The word “[ranga](http://www.australiantimes.co.uk/ranga-added-to-new-edition-of-australian-oxford-dictionary/)”:

> - ***is a term used by Australians to refer to red-haired people, often in an offensive manner***. It is now set to be the latest Australian slang term to enter an officially recognized lexicon, with its inclusion in the new edition of the Australian Oxford Dictionary.
> - Examining the history of the word and its role in current Australian society the Australian National Dictionary Centre noted that red-haired people in Australia have long attracted attention and nicknames from their non red-headed brethren, including *bluey, ginger, bloodnut, fantapants* and *Annie*.
> - “They are also popularly stereotyped as emotional, volatile, and quick to anger … it seems that red-haired people are unfairly labeled as a result of their hair colour.”
> - ***The word originated from an abbreviation of orang-utan, primates native to the rainforests of Indonesia and Malaysia known for their reddish-brown hair.***

(australiantimes.co.uk)